# aタグにonclickの挿入

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<a href="example.com" class="a">
```

上記のようなaタグに正規表現を使用して、onclickイベントを追加したいと考えています。
どのようにすればうまくいきますでしょうか。
詳しい方、ご教示ください。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: タグにjavascriptとphpの両方が入っていますが、プログラムを実装したいのはサーバ側(php)ですか？それともクライアント側(javascript)ですか？

Answer (score 1):

正規表現ではありませんが[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)関数を利用するとこんな感じでしょうか。

```js
function someFunction(event) {
    console.log(event);
}

var aList = document.querySelectorAll('a.a');

for (var i = 0; i < aList.length; i++) {
  aList[i].onclick = someFunction;
}
```

```html
<a href="example.com" class="a">example.com</a>
<a href="sub.example.com" class="a">sub.example.com</a>
```